# R: how to do multiple looping with sappy or lapply

Tags: r

I'm a beginner with R, and before then I used to use for loops 
when doing macros.
However after learning R, I got to learn this interesting command `sapply`&
`lapply` but wondering how I can use this command for multiple looping.

For instance, when I was using for loop to perform simultaneous jobs,
I nested for loop in a for loop such as an example below:

```
 for i in ~~~{
            for j in ~~~~~ 
       }
 }
```

After learning `sapply` & `lapply`, I found out myself repeating same commands over and over since I don't know how to do multiple looping with these commands.
For example, below is the code for splitting file directory strings and return
7th and 8th chunk into the vector.

```
dir3<-sapply(strsplit(as.character(dir2),split="/",fixed=TRUE),function(x) (x[7]))
dir4<-as.list(dir3)
code<-do.call(rbind, dir4)
colnames(code)<-c("code")

dir5<-sapply(strsplit(as.character(dir2),split="/",fixed=TRUE),function(x) (x[8]))
dir6<-as.list(dir5)
fyear<-do.call(rbind, dir6)
colnames(fyear)<-c("fyear")
```

Is there any way I can perform the same task(=2nd looping) without copying the same command lines? 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just `*apply` the output of an `*apply` command.

I.e.:

```
sapply(
   sapply( 1:10, function(x) x^2 ), 
   function(x) x^3
)
```

Obviously there's a better way to do the above example, but you get the point.

Another way would be to use `mapply` with `expand.grid`.